# Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-8.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, ubuntu, blazor, .net-8.0

I've moved of my applications to .Net 8 and I use ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS VPS to host my web applications.

I'm trying to install .net 8 on the VPS but I can't

I've tried the [Scripted install](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) by microsoft it didn't work

I've tried the [Debian install](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian) by microsoft it didn't work

When I run the basic command for ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0
```

I get the following errer even after updating & Upgrading ubuntu

[image]

Comment: I would said the package is not yet available through apt-get. You might try to install manually from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0

Comment: How can I install manually along side with .net 6 and .net 7 as I run deferent applications on the same VPS that uses .net6&7 ? @dropoutcoder

Comment: Heads-up: Your Ubuntu may not support all versions of .NET. For example, [Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't support .NET 8+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-1804#supported-versions).

Answer (score 40):

Was in the same boat and between multiple GitHub posts for past releases was able to figure this out. Looks like dotnet-sdk-8.0 is not part of official Linux package so have to jump through a few hoops.

First use "sudo apt-get remove" command to remove the currently installed dotnet-sdk, dotnet-runtime and dotnet-host.

Then run the following command to add microsoft package source.

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Now you can run commands to install the new dotnet-host (on dotnet 8) and dotnet-sdk.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-host
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0
```

If you get any conflicts on install with existing installed packages, you have to uninstall those packages first.

Comment: unfortunately "sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0" didn't work

Comment: It seems working with a lot of people I don't know why your solution doesn't work with me 

Comment: Referring to the official doc, it's safer to check the Ubuntu version and use that to download the correct .deb file. The script is under this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#register-the-microsoft-package-repository

Comment: it's going to make it into the public official linux packages eventually, other options I tried haven't worked for me. The new chiseled containers also have .net 8 so maybe that's another option, i haven't tried it myself though: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-chiseled-containers/

Comment: worked for me when I ran Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS from a docker container.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working by doing the following;

```
sudo apt-get install -y gpg
wget -O - https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt-get update && \
   sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Dmitri M.

First I saw a conflict against "netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-7.0", I wrote down this:

```
sudo apt-get remove  netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-7.0
```

Then run again all these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-host
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

With sudo su:

```
apt-get remove dotnet-sdk-8.0
sudo apt autoremove
apt-get install -y dotnet-host
apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0
```